# How to wrap/unwrap with TPM2 endorsement key

Tags: tpm, trust, trusted-computing

I have a remote client A which wants to communicate securely with a server B having a discrete TPM. My understanding is that each TPM normally come with a endorsement key from manufacture like Infineon. Therefore, client A can validate client B's unique identity indirectly through TPM endorsement certificate by checking it against manufacture's CA certificate. This can be easily achieved by retrieving ek certificate from TPM NV index (below) or tpm2_getekcertifcate command, then send it to client A.

```
tpm2_nvread 0x1C00002 > rsa_cert
```

Since endorsement key is a storage root key, it should not be used as an encryption key according to information I found online. However, it can be used to wrap/unwrap a symmetric encryption key to be used in the subsequent operation. This means client can extract public from EK certificate and wrap an encryption key with it and send back to server B, but the problem is I could not figure out how to unwrap a file with private part of endorsement key. Could someone give me some guidance on this?

Thanks